# Having trouble to extract data from xml

Tags: php, xml, api, xml-parsing

i am trying to grab data from xml, but having issues.

I have create simple codes but i don't think they are going well..

```
<?php
    $cricapi = 'http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml';

    function followers($url) {  
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $mthType = $xml->match['type'];
        if ( $mthType == "ODI") 
        {
            $match = $xml->match['mchDesc'];
            return $match;
        }

    }
?>
```

and calling as

```
<?php echo $match = followers($cricapi); ?>
```

but i am unable to fetch results.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am trying make a something like http://www.hamariweb.com/

[image]

please help me to solve this .. thank you all

Comment: What is the exact issue? "but i am unable to fetch results" is not a specific question.

Comment: please try to run this script.. I apply a condition if the type == ODI then extract the match Description, but the script only check 1st type and don't run again .. even i tried foreach loop :(

Comment: Did you try using the data_is_url flag instead of curl? Try `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url,0,true);` only for retrieving the xml.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that as match is an array of matches, you cannot use $match['type'] but have to iterate over matches like this:

```
function followers($url) {  
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url,1,true);
  foreach($xml->match AS $match){
    if($match['type']== "ODI"){
      echo $match['mchDesc'];
    }
  }
}
```

Also you don't need the curl. If there is no reason, you can always use the data_is_url and then give the SimpleXMLElement the url!

Answer (score 1):

You have using wrong method for this,in general :-

```
$found = $xml->xpath("//match[@type='ODI']");
// is an array of collection that with node name is match, and attribute type=ODI
```

When there are repeated node name (match),
it will render as list of objects (array),
you can't just use `$xml->match`,
but `$xml->match[0], $xml->match[1] ...`

as for the attribute, you can use [`attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

anyway, long story short, use the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) is the easier solution

Comment: i didn't clearly understand .. can you please descibe a little bit

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$mthType[] = $xml->match['type'];
if ( $mthType == "ODI") {
    ...
}
```

The first sentence will give you a set of elements matching your condition.
You can not just apply a comparison as if it were a simple variable. You should iterate the returned elements. Or you should apply a filter to get just those elements "match" whose attribute "type" is "ODI".

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with your XML parsing, it's with your $mthType checking, specifically these two lines:

```
$mthType[] = $xml->match['type'];
if ( $mthType == "ODI")
```

You're setting $mthType up as an array, then only returning it if it matches a string, which will never happen. Remove the empty array-creation brackets from the first assignment, and that should put you on the right track.

```
$mthType = $xml->match['type'];
if ( $mthType == "ODI")
```

Comment: sorry i wrongly type, but i also try that way tooo.. but same response :(

Comment: Sometimes you have to explicitly give the (string) data type when dealing with the result of SimpleXML. Try this line: $mthType = (string)$xml->match['type'];  OR, use xpath as suggested in the other answer, which would be preferred.